# request.settimeout nodejs doesnt seem to be working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm calling a couple of webservices which can take up to 5-10 minutes to respond. Nodejs is giving me several ECONNRESET errors....

```
var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
  req.setTimeout(600000)
}
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: `.setTimeout()` can't do much good if you only call it _after_ the response has come back.

Answer (score 1):

You should call .setTimeout on the request object immediately it is created, i.e. not within the response callback as you have it.

```
var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
  // handle response
}).setTimeout(600000);
```

See https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback